# background-size doesn't work in IE

Tags: css, sprite, css-sprites

I'm using this `class` and this `id` (for instance) to add a picture on one div :

```
.icones { 
    background: transparent url('../contents/homepage/60/icones.png') no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 48px;
    background-size: 60px;
}
#contact {
    background-position: 0px -60px;
}
```

With `Chrome`, everything is ok, all looks great and all properties are shown in the `element inspector`, but in `IE`, there is a problem.

On inspecting the page with a developper tool on `IE`, I saw that "`background-size`" doesn't appear.

I know that it's that problem that gives me the trouble because when I hide it on `chrome` I have the same page than in `IE`.

So my question is: How can I force `IE` to apply this `background-size`?

THANKS!

**EDIT :**

So even with the filter, it doesn't seems to work:

```
    .icones { 
        background: transparent url('../contents/homepage/60/icones.png') no-repeat;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 50px;
        height: 48px;
        background-size: 60px;

        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='../contents/homepage/60/icones.png',sizingMethod='scale');
        -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='../contents/homepage/60/icones.png',sizingMethod='scale')";
}
#contact {
    background-position: 0px -60px;
}
```

**Solution :**

Edit the pictures size manually and forget the background-size. All is okay!

Comment: what version of IE do you have?

Comment: @clement, your question already has a solution. Check the link above. Also next time before you ask a quesion in SO make sure its not asked before

Comment: @MrLister : Thanks for your advice but I already tried that solution :-/

Comment: @Anamaria : Thanks but it doesn't work for the moment I probably made a moistake, I edit my initial post ;-)

Comment: @Anamaria : my problem is about the background-size! I resize the background before making the sprite!

Comment: @MrLister : I edited the post angain ;-)

Answer (score 0):

For IE you have to use a specific css filter:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
src='images/image.png',
sizingMethod='scale');

-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
src='images/image.png',
sizingMethod='scale')";
```

Or use jquery to achieve the effect, like it is explained in this [link](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/).

Comment: Thanks Antonio . I made it but it doesn't seems to work in my project (see my updated initial post)